# How can I locate the correct username and password tags?

Tags: java, php, html, screen-scraping

I want to scrape this website:
https://studentservices.uwo.ca/secure/index.cfm
But there is a login system. I am attempting to use htmlUnit in a native Java application (potentially for Android later). But I cannot understand how to locate the appropriate tags to allow the user to enter their info in my program.

Comment: A friend told me that potentially the username-password system is implemented in PHP and I need to locat that link from within the html

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are two ways you could approach this:

- Ask the people who maintain the site how to implement login *programmaticaly*.  (And while you are at it, check with them that what you are planning to do is *permitted*.  It is better to ask first, and avoid the risk of getting into trouble with your university administration.)
- Reverse engineer what the page is doing when you log in using a web browser.

One way to reverse engineering the page is to look at the page source, read the HTML and (try to) figure out what would happen when the user clicks the login button.  (That part of the page looks like a straight-forward HTML form ...)

If that approach doesn't give you the answer, then install and/or enable the web development tools in your browser, and use them to look at the actual HTTP requests that are sent when you login.

Answer (score 0):

you mean how to get like autologin?
**https://studentservices.uwo.ca/services/placeholder.cfm?userName={username}&passWord={password}**

Comment: I wouldn't even need autologin - just to give the user a form where they can enter their info, then once the login I will scrape the content of their profile for them